# Symfony3 - My handwritten post form don't work

Tags: forms, post, symfony

I'm trying to learn how to work with Symfony3.
I'm trying to make a simple form to connect. The form is succefully redirecting me to my page /login so that is super. But it don't sent to the page the post informations :/ Do you know how to do ?
This is my controller's code :

```
    public function showAction(Request $request){
        $motDePasse = $request->request->get("motDePasse", "");
        $identifiant = $request->request->get("identifiant", "");

        if($motDePasse  != "" && $identifiant != ""){
            // I make my user object and put it in $_SESSION
        }

        return $this->render("login/show.html.twig", [
            "identifiant" => $identifiant
        ]);
    }
```

And there is my twig code :

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <div id='loginBox'>
        <div class='center'>
            <div class='logo'></div>
            <h1>HyperPlanning</h1>
            <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method='post'>
                <input name='identifiant' type='text'     placeholder='Identifiant' value="{{ identifiant }}"><br/>
                <input name='motDePasse'  type='password' placeholder='Mot de passe'><br/>
                <input name='remember'    type='hidden' value='0'><br>
                <input name='remember'    type='checkbox' value='1' checked>    <span>Rester connecter</span><br>
                <input type='submit' value='Se connecter'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the form builder?

Comment: Yap, because I have difficulties to use it. I tryed to use a form builder but it need to create an object at the form submit (i don't want). So I tryed a form builder without object and i get the error : Could not load type "form". And I don't find any help on Google ... (This sentence can't exist ^^)

Comment: You can use `dump($request)` to see what information is actually being submitted to the controller, maybe that helps.

Comment: Thx @Karolis, I'm using the app_dev.php page and when I'm wathing on the  dev bottom bar, it's saying me no post data exist :/

Comment: I see.  In your html form you arre using the "login" path but the action is called "show". Probably the problem is here.

Comment: Thx @AMartinNo1, so you wan't me to type what ? login/show ? ^^

Comment: @J.Doe The fully path. You can see the name of the path in the dev bar on the bottom of your page.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 Route name : login ?

Comment: @J.Doe I have developed a simple form based on yours. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a configured Symfony3 project on my laptop but Symfony v2.7. However, I assume the script is going to work in Symfony3 as well.

I have a `DefaultController` with the actions `login` and `manageLogin`. The first action contains the above html form and the second makes a dump of `$request`. Both actions have as route name the respective actionName. In the html form I am using as action="..." the route name of the `manageLoginAction`.

When submitting the form the `manageLoginAction` is rendered.

**DefaultController:**

```
<?php
// [...]
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
// [...]

/**
 * @Route("/konto/login", name="login")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    return array(
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
    );
}
/**
 * @Route("/konto/manageLogin", name="manageLogin")
 * @Template()
 */
public function manageLoginAction(Request $request)
{
    dump($request);
    die;
}

// [...]
}
```

**login.twig.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
            <div id='loginBox'>
                <div class='center'>
                    <div class='logo'></div>
                    <h1>HyperPlanning</h1>
                    <form action="{{ path('manageLogin') }}" method='post'>
                    <input name='identifiant' type='text'     placeholder='Identifiant' value="Identifier"><br/>
                    <input name='motDePasse'  type='password' placeholder='Mot de passe'><br/>
                    <input name='remember'    type='hidden' value='0'><br>
                    <input name='remember'    type='checkbox' value='1' checked>                <span>Rester connecter</span><br>
                    <input type='submit' value='Se connecter'>
                </form>
            </div>
       </div>
   {% endblock %}
   {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
   </body>
```

**dump($request):**

[image: Dump of var $request]

Comment: Thanks a lot @AMartinNo1, your code works, i found the problem, my controller who is generating my form create an action to itself, can i do it ?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, you can use the same action for showing the form and handling the submitted content. As my answer has solved your issue can you upvote it / mark it as correct answer? Ty.

Comment: I waill, i can't redirect to the same controller (don't know why) but i can with an other :D thx

Comment: @J.Doe A redirect in the controller like in native php  `header('Location: index.php')`?